# To change the direction of collapsible panel to up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the collapsible panel direction to up.

Kindly See the link as :

http://dev.genuusdemo.com/demo/

JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".accordion_example2").smk_Accordion({
            closeAble: true, //boolean
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: By `collapsible panel direction to up` what do you intend to do?

Comment: @ArinCool : Actually my collaps panel should open to up direction not to down direction. In this demo the panel is opening in down direction, I want it to open in up direction

Comment: What do you mean exactly with up?I think that opening direction depends on the panel which is currently opened. For example, if the first panel is currently opened and you click on the third, opening direction is up because it can fill the space left from the closure of the first panel.

Comment: @Giorgio : I have updated the url. Kindly check. I want it to open on up direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just anchor it at the bottom instead of top, and it will open upwards...

```css
#accordion{
  width:400px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({collapsible: true});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have used it the same. But my panel should open in up direction and main heading i.e. title should go down

Comment: I cannot achieve to run the code above. What are the possibilites causing that? I firstly thought it was about some library issues but they are all included and still cannot run it.

Answer (score 0):

this.clickHead = function() {

```
    plugin.on('click', '.acc_head', function(){

        var s_parent = $(this).parent();

        if( s_parent.hasClass('acc_active') == false ){
            if( settings.closeOther ){
                plugin.find('.acc_content').slideUp(settings.slideSpeed);
                plugin.find('.accordion_in').removeClass('acc_active');
            }   
        }

        if( s_parent.hasClass('acc_active') ){
            if( false !== settings.closeAble ){
                s_parent.children('.acc_content').slideUp(settings.slideSpeed);
                s_parent.removeClass('acc_active');
            }
        }
        else{
            // changed the next to prev
            $(this).prev('.acc_content').slideDown(settings.slideSpeed);
            s_parent.addClass('acc_active');
        }

    });
```

I modified the smk-accordian.js slightly and the HTML

```
    <div class="accordion_in active">
        <div class="acc_content">
fg<!-- Your text here. For this demo, the content is generated automatically.-->
    </div>
    <div class="acc_head">
        <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>Section 1
    </div>
    </div>
```