# how to change collapse direction of a panel in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a well-known basic collapsible panel which its codes mentioned belowed. I changed some properties via css sets like collapse-in and collapse height&width but could not achieve to change collapsing direction. I want to change it towards top opposite to default position. How can I do that? I assure you that I tried several ways but could not solve the issue.

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
                    </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us more about what you tried? Perhaps someone can then explain why those attempts failed, making the question&answer more useful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just interchange the positions of `.panel-heading` and `#collapse1`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
                </div>

<div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not enough.I edited my question with a scheme including exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @SophisticatedUndoing - Okay, I understood your exact requirement. Let me try.

Comment: @SophisticatedUndoing - I think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979104/to-change-the-direction-of-collapsible-panel-to-up)