# Change panel width when collapse in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I'm trying to change the collapse behavior in bootstrap, but without success.

I want to create a page with small panels (maybe `col-md-4` that I named tabs) that changes the width after click, when the panel collapse.

Here is a example first page:

[image: tabs_closed_panels]

Here is the same page after click in the "tabs":

[image: collapsed_open_panels]

My current code, can't hide the `<div>something here</div>` and change the panel's width.

Below is the code for one panel with simple collapse effect.

```
<section class="col-md-4">
 <h3 class="page-header title">Forms</h3>
 <div class="panel-group">
   <div id="panel-form-1" class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">
           <h4 class="panel-title">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel1"> Panel #1</a>
           </h4>
       </div>
       <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
           <div class="panel-body">
               <form role="form" id="form1">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div>Stuff</div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </form>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-footer">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Other panels-->
 </div>
         </section> 
 <div class="col-md-8 something">Something here</div>
```

JS (not working. No console errors):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   $(this).parent("section").removeClass("col-md-4").addClass("col-md-12");
   $(document).find("div.something").hide();
});
</script>
```

My result page with opened panels is something like (please ignore the glyphicon problems):

[image: result page]

I tried to follow the example in this another [question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756985/how-to-change-collapse-direction-of-a-panel-in-bootstrap), but I didn't understand it very well.

Is it possible achieve it using bootstrap?

Misc:

- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- JQuery 3.1.1
- Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Can you post all of the code? Also, what happens to "Something here" when the panels are open it disappears? What happens to the tabs when one panel is open? They're still smaller width?

Comment: Yes for both your questions. The panel's behavior are independent each other and when any of them opens, the div "Something here" disappear. On my code, I'll paste my JS, but actually it isn't changing anything.